# Loading GeoJSON overlay into Folium raises ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I am trying to load a county border map (.geojson file) into Folium and getting a ValueError.

The GeoJSON file was pulled from here:
https://data.mo.gov/Demographics/Missouri-County-Boundaries-Map/n34b-fwqr

It looks like:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"co_class":"3","acres":"327632.419997","pop_1990":"7547","cnty_seat":"Kahoka","countyname":"Clark","name_ucase":"CLARK","countygnis":"758477","countyfips":"045","pop_2000":"7416","sq_miles":"511.92565625"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-91.72916190319887,40.61370307324286],[-91.7211904460685,40.60303954172671],[-91.7200583614958,40.60152712696914],
```

...

I have validated the file using GeoPandas and it seems to load and display properly there.  I have also tried loading the .json version but receive the same result.

```
import folium as f
import pathlib as pl

MO_LAT = 37.9643
MO_LONG = -91.8318
county_gjson = pl.Path.cwd() /"data" / "Missouri County Boundaries Map.geojson"
m = f.Map(
    location=[MO_LAT, MO_LONG],
    tiles='Mapbox Bright',
    zoom_start=7
)

f.GeoJson(
    county_gjson,
    name='geojson'
).add_to(m)
f.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save("mymap.html")
```

I am hoping to have an overlay of the Missouri County boundaries.  When I run the code I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Missouri/mo_counties.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Missouri')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-bdbf561151e1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Missouri/mo_counties.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Missouri')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Missouri/mo_counties.py", line 23, in <module>
    name='geojson'

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 447, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Cannot render objects with any missing geometries. {!r}'.format(data))

ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries. WindowsPath('C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Missouri/data/Missouri County Boundaries Map.geojson')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs since `geoJSON` function expects GeoJSON object instead of a file path:

```
f.GeoJson(
    county_gjson,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    expects a valid GeoJSON object
).add_to(m)
```

To read GeoJSON from a file [`json.load()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) could be utilized:

```
county_path = os.path.join(pl.Path.cwd(),'data', 'Missouri County Boundaries Map.geojson') 
county_geojson = json.load(open(county_path))
```

**Modified example**

```
import folium as f
import json
import os

MO_LAT = 37.9643
MO_LONG = -91.8318
county_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'data', 'Missouri County Boundaries Map.geojson') 
county_geojson = json.load(open(county_path))

m= f.Map(
    location=[MO_LAT, MO_LONG],
    tiles='Mapbox Bright',
    zoom_start=7
)

f.GeoJson(
    county_geojson,
    name='geojson'
).add_to(m)
f.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save("./mymap.html")
```